# Converting XML to Json with HTML string data in angular 8

Tags: javascript, json, angular, xml, typescript

I have XML document that I am trying to convert to JSON but some of the string fields have HTML tags in them. The source XML looks like this:

```
<title>
    <html>
        <p>test</p>
    </html>
</title>
```

i have tried npm packages like xml2js and fast-xml-parser. They are parsing html tags also to json. can anyone suggest any other npm package or solution that would be helpful

Expected output should be:

```
{
    "title": "<html><p>test</p></html>"
}
```

Comment: That **isn't** string data. If it was string data then either the special characters would be escaped (e.g. `<` would be `&lt;`) or would be wrapped in `CDATA` markers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try fast-xml-parser with `stopNodes` option to parse a node as a string.

```
let jsonObj = parser.parse(xmlData,{
    stopNodes = ["title"]
});
```